# Can you clear setInterval if a condition is met? without using componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, this

Im creating a simple timer. I want the timer to reset everytime it reaches 00 seconds. Im using setInterval but its not clearing everytime value is 0 in this.state.seconds. Ive seen some solutions using componentDidMount and componentDidUnmount but would be interested in getting to execute and clear setInterval from the method that calls setInterval itself. Is this something possible to do?

Untill now timer continues decreasing even after 0 seconds. Here is my codepen draft: https://codepen.io/tonytony92/pen/bGdJeRg

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            minutes: 25,
            seconds: 59,
            play: false,
            display: "SESSION"
        }
        this.handlePlay = this.handlePlay.bind(this)
    }


    handlePlay() {
        let func1 = () => {
            this.setState({
                seconds: this.state.seconds - 1
            })
            console.log(this.state.seconds)
        }

        if (this.state.seconds > 0) {
            this.Myvar = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(this.state.seconds)
                this.setState({
                    seconds: this.state.seconds - 1
                })
            }, 200)
        }
        else {
            console.log("minus")
            clearInterval(this.Myvar)  /// not clearing ///
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handlePlay` launches the timer when the button is clicked bu does not check for the remaining as you would expect.

This is because the function provided to `setInterval` is

```
console.log(this.state.seconds)
this.setState({
  seconds: this.state.seconds - 1
})
```

and not the function `handlePlay`.

For better readability and maintanability (and also have the code to work), split the logic that handles time decrease from the code that launches the timer. Like this:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 10,
            play: false,
            display: "SESSION"
        }
        this.handlePlay = this.handlePlay.bind(this);
        this.handleTime = this.handleTime.bind(this);
    }

    // handlePlay only launches the timer.
    handlePlay() {
        this.Myvar = setInterval(this.handleTime, 200);
    }

    // handleTime deals with the logic of decrementing time.
    handleTime() {
        if (this.state.seconds > 0) {
            console.log(this.state.seconds)
            this.setState({
                seconds: this.state.seconds - 1
            })
        } else {
            console.log("minus")
            clearInterval(this.Myvar)
        }
    }
}
```

`handlePlay` is now the interface between the UI (button click) and the logic (handle time decrease). It only launches the timer with `setInterval`.

`handleTime` handles the logic of the time decrease. It's called every time `setInterval` fires and stops the timer once time is over.

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering. So I implemented your solution and the timer stops when it reaches 0. Im still trying to implement a way to start/stop the timer with the onclick attribute since it seems that as soon as this.state.seconds>0 evaluates to false , the else code block runs undefinately since this.handleTimer is still executing recursively. It seems clearInterval is not clearing interval. If you run the timer you can see console.log for the else statement is still logging infinitely. here is the code with your contribution https://codepen.io/tonytony92/pen/bGdJeRg?editors=1111

Comment: I understand your concern. Before having a look at your code, this request of stoping the timer when clicking a second time on the button is not part of your original post so you can leave my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Its already working , I added the following code: handlePlay(){
    if(this.state.play===false){
       this.myVar=setInterval(this.handleTimer,200);
      this.setState({
        play:true
      })
    }
   else if(this.state.play===true){
     clearInterval(this.myVar)
     this.setState({
       play:false
     })
   }
   
  }